# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'author')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The error above occurs when I submit a blank form. The API I'm submitting to will throw an error since it should not be left blank. I can't seem to get my head around this. I apologize if this code is poorly-written, but I'm guessing it has to do with one of the pieces of state being undefined when the page is rendered. It seems as if the "catch" block of "handleSubmit" is changing the data state to something undefined.

```
import "./Homepage.css"
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react"
import useFetch from "./useFetch"
import Axios from "axios"

export default function Homepage() {
  const [body, setBody] = useState("")
  const [sortedData, setSortedData] = useState("")
  const [data, setData] = useState("")
  const [errorFlash, setErrorFlash] = useState("")
  const [successFlash, setSuccessFlash] = useState("")
  const posts = useFetch("http://localhost:5000/api/data")
  const firstRender = useRef(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(posts) //initiates data on first render
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstRender.current) {
      firstRender.current = false // Will prevent function from running on first render
      return
    }
    data.sort(function (a, b) {
      return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date)
    })
    setSortedData(data)
  }, [data]) // Dependency set to "data" state, should run after data is fetched

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    Axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/react-create-post", { text: body }, { withCredentials: true })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data)
        setSuccessFlash(res.data.msg) // res.data.msg is "Successfully created post"
        setSortedData((prevArray) => [res.data.post, ...prevArray])
        setBody("")
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setErrorFlash("Field cannot be left blank")
      })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <center>
        <div className="create-container">
          <div className="posts-title">Create Post</div>
          <form id="theForm" onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
            <textarea onChange={(e) => setBody(e.target.value)} value={`${body}`} id="theInput" className="post-input" name="text" type="text"></textarea>
            <button className="submit-btn">POST</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div id="postsContainer" className="posts-container">
          <div className="posts-title">Latest Posts</div>
          {errorFlash ? <div className="error-msg">{errorFlash}</div> : console.log()}
          {successFlash ? <div className="success-msg">{successFlash}</div> : console.log()}
          <div id="postInput">
            {sortedData &&
              sortedData.map((item) => {
                return (
                  <div className="post-container" key={item._id}>
                    <a className="a" href={`/user/${item.author}`}>
                      <h3 className="author">{item.author}</h3>
                    </a>
                    <div className="date">{item.date.toLocaleString()}</div>
                    <div className="options-cont">
                      <button id="optionsBtn" className="options-btn">
                        <i className="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                      </button>
                      <button data-author={`${item.author}`} data-id={`${item._id}`} data-text={`${item.body}`} id="editBtn" className="edit inside-btn invisible">
                        Edit
                      </button>
                      <button data-author={`${item.author}`} data-id={`${item._id}`} id="deleteBtn" className="delete inside-btn invisible">
                        Delete
                      </button>
                      <br></br>
                      <button className="invisible-two">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                    <p className="body-text">{item.body}</p>
                  </div>
                )
              })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </center>
    </div>
  )
}

//useFetch hook in useFetch.js file

import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

export default function useFetch(url) {
  const [data, setData] = useState("")
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((info) => {
        setData(info)
      })
  }, [url])
  return data
}


///API Code
exports.apiPostCreate = function (req, res) {
  let post = new Post(req.body.text, req.verifiedUser.item.username)
  post
    .create()
    .then((item) => {
      res.status(201).send({ post: item, msg: "Post successfully created" })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(201).send({ err }) //This is what gets sent back in the "catch" block of the client-side
    })
}
```

Basically the error occurs when the "catch" block of "handleSubmit" executes. Everything else seems to work okay.

Comment: Is `{ text: body }` correct for the body of a POST request? Have you checked your network tab to ensure you are forming the request correctly, or to see what you are POSTing? If the error is occurring on the server-side then what debugging have you done there? Can you include all relevant code you've an issue with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the error. In my API after an unsuccessful post attempt I original had this code:

```
res.status(201).send({ err })
```

This means that "then" was still executing on the Axios request. I since changed the status code to 500 and now everything works properly.